# Using <input type=file> in react native

Tags: react-native

Is there anywhere i can use a similar function like the  in react native to upload image and take picture? I need to push this function via code-push, if i'm using library like react-native-image-picker, i can't push it via code-push. Or is there any pure js library can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible as the code you'd need to achieve what you want requires access to native APIs (read/write storage, camera, etc.). You will therefore need to push an actual update through the App Store and Google Play.